# How to get variable value from Javascript using Selenium with Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, dom

Using Selenium, the following is the code I am running on Python to get my geo-coordinates via use of the navigator web api:

```
        coordinates = driver.execute_script(
        " return () => {                                            " +
        "   var savedCoordinates;                                   " +
        "                                                           " +
        "   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(               " +
        "       (pos) => savedCoordinates = pos.coords,             " +
        "       error,                                              " +
        "       options);                                           " +
        "                                                           " +
        "   let options = {                                         " +
        "       enableHighAccuracy: true,                           " +
        "       timeout: 5000,                                      " +
        "       maximumAge: 0                                       " +
        "   };                                                      " +
        "                                                           " +
        "   function error(err) {                                   " +
        "       console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`); " +
        "   };                                                      " +
        "                                                           " +
        " return savedCoordinates;                                  " +
        " }                                                         " ) 
        print(coordinates)
```

Expected output: `{latitude: XXX.XXX, longitude XX.XXXX}`

Actual output: `{}`

Can someone help me figure out how I can get my geo-coordinates using this method?

Comment: We're going to need to see the page source, no?

Comment: page source is just google.com opened up on Chrome

Comment: first you could use `consoler.log()` or `alert()` to display values in variables and to see if code is executed

Comment: console.log(savedCoordinates) works fine

Comment: try without `return () => { }`

Comment: it seems it defines function and returns this function, not value from function. You have to run this function `return (() => { .... })()`

Answer (score 0):

It should work without `return () => { }`

```
    coordinates = driver.execute_script(
    "   var savedCoordinates;                                   " +
    "                                                           " +
    "   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(               " +
    "       (pos) => savedCoordinates = pos.coords,             " +
    "       error,                                              " +
    "       options);                                           " +
    "                                                           " +
    "   let options = {                                         " +
    "       enableHighAccuracy: true,                           " +
    "       timeout: 5000,                                      " +
    "       maximumAge: 0                                       " +
    "   };                                                      " +
    "                                                           " +
    "   function error(err) {                                   " +
    "       console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`); " +
    "   };                                                      " +
    "                                                           " +
    " return savedCoordinates;                                  " ) 

    print(coordinates)
```

As for me this `() => {}` only defines function but it doesn't run it - so it returns this function, not result from function. You may need `()` to run it

```
return (() => {...code...})()
```